# How to create and display hierarchy list in servicenow?

Tags: servicenow, servicenow-rest-api

Dean-> manager -> senior faculty -> junior faculty -> students

The above structure is in hierarchical form and when I open dean form in servicenow I should be able to see record i.e. rest of the staff under him. Similarly in manager I should be able to see below him.......and so on for junior faculty I will be able to see students and for students there should be no record

Comment: What have you tried? Please update the question

Comment: I have tried scripting in run script option but I didn't get any result

Comment: Also I was thinking to create manually creating a related list and adding users manually but it will be too long and for that I have to add manually for each user

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you can create hierarchical related lists assuming you are using the List V2.

Check here:
https://docs.servicenow.com/bundle/orlando-platform-administration/page/administer/list-administration/task/t_EnableAHierarchicalList.html

I'm not sure this is 100% what you're after but it is a start. I think that in general a better idea is just to create simple Related Lists which allow the user to hop from one table to another. You don't always need to show everything in one view.